# Create flexible mtd partitions

Tags: linux-kernel, partitioning, u-boot

I would like to populate partitions depend on its content. During system boot I would like to check if the flash area contain any data. If true - make it visible read-only, or rewritable.

I would like to make it automatically, without U-boot shell...

On Linux kernel level I can make it only statically in partition table.
Is it possible to do it in U-boot ?

Thank you for any hints.

#### Update: CmdLine and mtd_partition checked

I've checked two possibilities:
U-boot mtd-parts

```
U-Boot> 
setenv mtdparts mtdparts=atmel_nand:2M@0x40000(u-boot),30M@0x200000(kernel),-@0x2000000(user),**0x20000@0x100000(u)**

U-Boot>
mtdparts
```

no partitions allowed after a fill-up partition

Unfortunately its not possible to add partition at the and of table. I would like to have mtd4 as separate partition if the data exist in `0x100000` area.

It is possible in kernel mtd_partition table. But this table is declared in arch/arm... board file (early startup stage). On this startup stage I can not read nand. I don't have access to nand read interface provided by nand driver.

## Update: solution

Thank you for all hints. Following "artless noise" hints I decided to read nand area in u-boot, and send useful parameters via different kernel command line arguments. This is very flexible. Some other HW configurations can be stored in flash and used for kernel initialization.

Catching kernel parameters can be done via: `early_param()` function.

Comment: Have you looked in the source?  [Kconfig](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/mtd/Kconfig) gives RedBoot, CmdLine, AFS, OpenFirmware, AR7 and BCM63XX.  Which ones have you evaluated and are using?  You are also free to code your own in a machine file.  Before registering the MTD, most NAND drivers takes a `mtd_partition` which you can dynamically set.

Comment: I'm trying now, but its not easy to reach. Comments added

Comment: You are almost there.  Check [U-boot Linux command-line passing](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/LinuxKernelArgs).  The *traditional* u-boot variable is `bootargs`.  You need to append your `mtdparts` string to that variable.  You can see the command line at the top of the Linux log as it boots, if you have a console.  If you can read from `u-boot`, but not Linux, you can make your own argument **my_mtd_extra** and pass this on the command line.  Read this in the *board* file.

Comment: If you have solved this, please, post an answer.